# Problema declaraciones en clases (objetos)

Tags: c++

Debo desarrollar un programa implementando clases y objetos el cual al final me devuelva un nombre, el problema es que no entiendo a que se refiere cuando dice que no he declarado la variable "nombre" si lo esta, en el apartado de private

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programación c++\Ejercicio basico [1] construc\main.cpp|19|error: 'nombre' was not declared in this scope|
```

Este es el programa

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Persona {
 private:
     string nombre;

 public:
    Persona(string _nombre);
   string getNombre();

};

Persona::Persona(string _nombre){
     nombre = _nombre;
}
string getNombre(){
  return nombre;
}
int main (){

Persona persona1("Andres");
cout<<persona1.getNombre();


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltó incluir el `Persona::` antes de el nombre de tu función `getNombre()`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!